# Dask apply with custom function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

I am experimenting with Dask, but I encountered a problem while using `apply` after grouping.

I have a Dask DataFrame with a large number of rows. Let's consider for example the following

```py
N=10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':np.random.random(N), 'col_2': np.random.random(N) })
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)
```

I want to bin the values of `col_1` and I follow the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125665/simple-dask-map-partitions-example)

```py
bins = np.linspace(0,1,11)
labels = list(range(len(bins)-1))
ddf2 = ddf.map_partitions(test_f, 'col_1',bins,labels)
```

where

```py
def test_f(df,col,bins,labels):
    return df.assign(bin_num = pd.cut(df[col],bins,labels=labels))
```

and this works as I expect it to.

Now I want to take the median value in each bin (taken from [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4362#issuecomment-453179565))

```py
median = ddf2.groupby('bin_num')['col_1'].apply(pd.Series.median).compute()
```

Having 10 bins, I expect `median` to have 10 rows, but it actually has 80. The dataframe has 8 partitions so I guess that somehow the apply is working on each one individually.

However, If I want the mean and use `mean`

```py
median = ddf2.groupby('bin_num')['col_1'].mean().compute()
```

it works and the output has 10 rows.

The question is then: *what am I doing wrong that is preventing `apply` from operating  as `mean`?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this warning is the key ([Dask doc: SeriesGroupBy.apply](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.apply)) :

> Pandas’ groupby-apply can be used to to apply arbitrary functions, including aggregations that result in one row per group. Dask’s groupby-apply **will apply func once to each partition-group pair**, so when func is a reduction you’ll end up with one row per partition-group pair. To apply a custom aggregation with Dask, use dask.dataframe.groupby.Aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

You are right! I was able to reproduce your problem on Dask 2.11.0. The good news is that there's a solution! It appears that the Dask groupby problem is specifically with the category type (pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.CategoricalDtype). By casting the category column to another column type (float, int, str), then the groupby will work correctly.

Here's your code that I copied:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def test_f(df, col, bins, labels):
    return df.assign(bin_num=pd.cut(df[col], bins, labels=labels))

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': np.random.random(N), 'col_2': np.random.random(N)})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)

bins = np.linspace(0,1,11)
labels = list(range(len(bins)-1))
ddf2 = ddf.map_partitions(test_f, 'col_1', bins, labels)

print(ddf2.groupby('bin_num')['col_1'].apply(pd.Series.median).compute())
```

which prints out the problem you mentioned

```
bin_num
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
       ...   
5    0.550844
6    0.651036
7    0.751220
8         NaN
9         NaN
Name: col_1, Length: 80, dtype: float64
```

Here's my solution:

```
ddf3 = ddf2.copy()
ddf3["bin_num"] = ddf3["bin_num"].astype("int")

print(ddf3.groupby('bin_num')['col_1'].apply(pd.Series.median).compute())
```

which printed:

```
bin_num
9    0.951369
2    0.249150
1    0.149563
0    0.049897
3    0.347906
8    0.847819
4    0.449029
5    0.550608
6    0.652778
7    0.749922
Name: col_1, dtype: float64
```

@MRocklin or @TomAugspurger
Would you be able to create a fix for this in a new release? I think there is sufficient reproducible code here. Thanks for all your hard work. I love Dask and use it every day ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking your time to investigate this! The solution I had chosen after reading ava-punksmash answer was to `compute` the dataframe and use `pandas'` `groupby` and `median`. However, next time I encounter a similar situation I will implement your suggestion!